# getting raw payload from JAX-WS service

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb, jax-ws

Having a SOAP based web service with XML payload, how can I grab the XML payload of the service response in JAX-WS >2.0 client?

I can see how this question will be marked as duplicate, but bear with me.

It seems that the options are:

1. Use [Dispatch API](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-ws-dispatch-api.html). However this would require me to go low(er) level and create the request payload manually, which I want to avoid.
2. Use [handler infrastructure](https://jax-ws.java.net/articles/handlers_introduction.html) of the JAX-WS to grab the payload and possibly pass it via MessageContext property back to the client, but this will still unmarshall the XML into JAXB Object tree, which I want to avoid.

So, how can I:

1. Call a web service using SEI - no messing with creating XML request from scratch
2. Grab the 'RAW' XML response without the JAXB unmarshalling happening

Sounds simple enough, right?

Comment: Which implementation are you using? CXF? Metro?

Comment: @Namphibian Does it matter? I want to do it in JAX-WS >2.0 compliant way, since the environment is mixed, some is Axis2, some is CXF

Comment: Yeah it does because each implementation is different.

Comment: Well, but they're all JAX-WS compliant, so I am looking for specification compliant way as opposed to implementation specific way

Answer (score 1):

Among the non-goals the JAX-WS 2 specification says that 
'Pluggable data binding JAX-WS 2.0 will defer data binding to JAXB[10]; it is not a goal to provide a
plug-in API to allow other types of data binding technologies to be used in place of JAXB. However,
JAX-WS 2.0 will maintain the capability to selectively disable data binding to provide an XML based
fragment suitable for use as input to alternative data binding technologies.'

So, you should be able to have access to the raw payload.

The following example is also in the specification :

4.3.5.5 Asynchronous, Callback, Payload-Oriented

```
class MyHandler implements AsyncHandler<Source> {

...
public void handleResponse(Response<Source> res) {
Source resMsg = res.get();
// do something with the results
}
}
Source reqMsg = ...;
Service service = ...;
Dispatch<Source> disp = service.createDispatch(portName,
Source.class, PAYLOAD);
MyHandler handler = new MyHandler();
disp.invokeAsync(reqMsg, handler);
```

Since the specification also states that a Binding has its own HandlerChain (see chapter 9) you should be able to remove the JAXB handler from the chain, so that JAXB marshalling/unmarshalling doesn't get involved.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I will need some time to evaluate this. The section 4.3.5.5 of the JAX-WS 2.0 spec that you  quote is referring to the Dispatch API. I thought that the idea was that you're doing everything 'manually' including the message creation, but maybe I need to read through it again.